# Enabling backgroundTap in uiscrollview without disabling uibuttons

Tags: uiscrollview, uibutton

So I have a uiscrollview with a form of textfields. I'm trying to add an action to the background so that when the user taps on the background the keyboard retracts.

I was able to get the backgroundTap to retract the keyboard, but it disabled my uibuttons: [Detecting hits in UIScrollView while still letting it do it's thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637161/detecting-hits-in-uiscrollview-while-still-letting-it-do-its-thing)

As stated in the second answer I added this code to the viewDidLoad:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(backgroundTap:)];

[scrollView addGestureRecognizer: singleTap];
```

Where backgroundTap is

```
- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender
```

That allowed me retract the keyboard with a backgroundTap on uiscrollview, however it disabled my cancelButton that closes the modal view of the form and also the submitButton which sends out a HTTP Post.

Any ideas why it's disabling the uibuttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some more searching and found the correct answer! I'll just post the link and answer here in case other people find this first.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTap:)];

singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
singleTapGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
singleTapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[tapableView addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGestureRecognizer];
[singleTapGestureRecognizer release];
```

Cheers,
J

[iOS5 UITapRecognizer for UIScrollView interfering with buttons. How to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250485/ios5-uitaprecognizer-for-uiscrollview-interfering-with-buttons-how-to-fix)